# How to dynamically compile Java classes in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-compiler-api, dynamic-compilation

In answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507027/can-i-use-javacompiler-in-google-app-engine), I learned that it is not possible to invoke the Java Compiler in `javax.tools` from a GAE app.

- Does this limitation still apply?
- If so, what are my options for compiling Java source code into loadable class files "on the fly"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `javax.tools` is still not on the Appengine's [JRE Class Whitelist](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html).

The options you have are:

1. Compile somewhere else and than transfer and load .class files on appengine.
2. Try using one of embeddable Java compilers: [Janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home), [JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/).
3. If you can live without Java, than you might try using [BeanShell for Appengine](http://mybeanshell.appspot.com/static/beanshell.html).